# Variance of a Derived Distribution from a Bernoulli Process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, variance

Here is a Bernoulli process:

*A network router accepts packets coming from two links. Time is divided into slots. A slot can be idle, with probability pI=1/6, and busy with probability pB=5/6. During a busy slot, there is probability p1|B=2/5 (respectively, p2|B=3/5) that a packet from link 1 (respectively, 2) is being rerouted. We assume that events related to different slots are independent.
The goal is to find the distribution of the PMF, mean, and variance of the **number of packets from link 2 until the time of the 5th packet from link 1** (let's call this random variable X).*

How do you go about this problem?

My idea is, employing Pascal distribution, the expected **number of slots up to and including the 5th packet from link 1** (let's call this random variable Y) is just $$5*\frac{1}{(5/6)*(2/5)}$$.

I am certain that the distribution of the PMF of X should be Pascal. My idea is that the mean of X should just be $$5*\frac{1}{(5/6)*(2/5)}*[(3/5)*(5/6)]$$ which is the mean time of the number of slots up to (and including) the 5th packet from link 1 or $E[Y]$ times the probability of a link 2 packet which is $[(3/5)*(5/6)]$. Similarly, for the variance, my idea is just to multiply var(Y) times the square of $[(3/5)*(5/6)]$. However, my professor told me that the resulting mean that I got for X is correct, however, the variance is not, because $X\ne[(3/5)*(5/6)]Y$. Why is this so? What is $X$ in terms of $Y$? And how do I find the mean and variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> number of packets from link 2 until the time of the 5th packet from link 1 (let's call this random variable X).

We are not concerned with the count of time slots.  We are counting the *number of packets*, which only appear during busy slots.

In order for $X=k$ we must see some *arrangement* of 4 packets from link#1 and $k$ packets from link#2 in some order, followed immediately by a final packet from link 1.   The rate of arrival of packets from link#1 during busy times is $p_{1\mid B}$, and from link#2 is $p_{2\mid B}$ .   So using this evaluate the pmf.

$$\mathsf P(X=k) = \bbox[lemonchiffon,1pt,border:dotted 1pt blue]{\qquad\qquad\color{silver}{\mid?}}\mathbf 1_{k\in \{0,1,\ldots\}}$$

This should be a distribution from a familiar family.

> Yes, it is negative binomial. Otherwise known as Pascal.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!